# Run ruby script in terminal with parameters

Tags: ruby

How would I run this method in terminal/irb and test out different parameters?

```
def add(*numbers)
  numbers.inject(0) { |sum, number| sum + number }
end
```

i.e trying the parameters 4 & 6 I would think something like:
`ruby add_method.rb 4,6` or `ruby add_method.rb(4,6)`
but can't find/figure out the exact execution code to make it work. When I run those I get no return just a new prompt.

Comment: Why not paste that method into `IRB` and then call `add 4, 6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it to a file like this:

```
def add(*numbers)
  numbers.inject(0) { |sum, number| sum + number }
end

result = add(*ARGV.map(&:to_i))
puts result
```

Then run it like `ruby add_method.rb 4 6`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the below code in a file *add.rb* :

```
def add(numbers)
  numbers.inject(0) { |sum, number| sum + number.to_i }
end

puts add(ARGV)
```

Now run as

```
ruby add.rb 1 2 3
```

And you will get the output as - `6`.

Read about [`ARGF`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html) -

> `ARGF` is a stream designed for use in scripts that process files given as command-line arguments or passed in via `STDIN`....

Comment: Bracket the test code with `if __FILE__ == $0; ...; end` so the test case only gets run when `add.rb` is directly invoked, but not when it is loaded by another script.

Comment: How would I do it with still keeping that splat operator? It was the focus on this lesson I'm doing.

Comment: @Jadam See konsolebox's answer to retain splat.